# Return function value from a nested on click function

Tags: jquery

How can I get the `success` instead of `undefined` when openModal is called?

```js
function deleteImg(model, name, id) {
  return 'success';
}
  
function openModal(model, name, id){
  $('#button').show();
  $('#button').on('click', function() {
//   console.log( deleteImg(model, name, id) );
     return deleteImg(model, name, id);
  })
}

console.log(openModal(1,2,3));
```

```css
#button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">
Button
</button>
```

I have also tried using `$.when().done()`;

```
function openModal(model, name, id){
    var status;
    $.when(
      $('#button').show(),
      $('#button').on('click', function() {
//      console.log( deleteImg(model, name, id) );
        status = deleteImg(model, name, id);
      })
    ).done(
      function(){
        return status;
      }
    )
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use callback pattern, just pass a function as a callback and call it from click listener.

```
function deleteImg(model, name, id) {
  return 'success';
}

function openModal(model, name, id, cb){
  $('#button').show();
  $('#button').on('click', function() {
     // return deleteImg(model, name, id);
     cb(deleteImg(model, name, id));
  })
}

openModal(1,2,3, function (res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```